# How do I combine multiples columns of data into their respective rows using Python

Tags: python, django, python-itertools

I having multiple lists that represent a column of data. I need to convert the column data into rows.

My approach to this problem has been attempting to iterate over each column and appending the appropriate items to a separate list. The data is structured in this way:

```
columns = [[column1], [column2], ... ]
```

My goal is to create something like:

```
row = [column1[1], column2[1], ...]
```

I can't quite figure out how to iterate over each column at the same time, grabbing the same index of each list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#zip) method:

```
>>> columns = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> rows = zip(*columns)
>>> rows
[(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
>>> rows[1]
(2, 5, 8)
```

Comment: Simple and effective, thank you. This is exactly what I needed.